# -moz-transition-duration not function

Tags: css, firefox, transition, duration

i have a problem whit this site http://www.lookcommunication.it/korus/WEPA/IT/index.php

The squares box(INDEX),in Chrome, have a -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; and all is ok.
But with FF this effect not function.

The shadow under the box have the same effect and in Chrome and FF function.

Why my box does not move?

Thanks for help

```
.label
{
position:relative; 
z-index:3;  
-webkit-transition-property: top, bottom; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
-moz-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
transition-duration: 0.4s; 
-o-transition:0.4s; 
-moz-transition-property: top, bottom;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because **Firefox doesn't know what value of `top` it must switch to.**

Indeed, Firefox sees that `top` is set to `-10px` in `.label:hover` but cannot find the value of `top` in the `label` declaration.

You simply have to set `top` to `0` in the `label` declaration:

```
.label {
    // Your code
    top: 0;
}
```

It works for me!

Comment: Actually, it does know what value to switch to: `auto`.  The problem is that per spec you can't interpolate between `auto` and a length, and Firefox follows the spec.